# Kotlin, Spring-boot and Maven: Unresolved reference: SpringBootApplication

Tags: maven, spring-boot, kotlin

I want to write a Kotlin application using Spring Boot.
I wrote the following pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<groupId> com.matan</groupId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>spring-5-mvc</artifactId>
<name>spring-5-mvc</name>
<description>spring 5 MVC sample project about new features</description>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <jayway-rest-assured.version>2.9.0</jayway-rest-assured.version>
    <jackson.version>2.9.9</jackson.version> <!-- Same as spring-boot-dependencies:2.1.7.RELEASE -->
    <kotlin.version>1.3.50</kotlin.version> <!-- Same as spring-boot-dependencies:2.1.7.RELEASE -->
    <start-class>com.matan.Main</start-class>
    <httpclient.version>4.5.8</httpclient.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- utils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--kotlin deps -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jre8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- runtime and test scoped -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${jayway-rest-assured.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerPlugins>
                    <plugin>spring</plugin>
                </compilerPlugins>
                <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I wrote the following Main class:

```
package com.matan;

@SpringBootApplication
class Main
```

and then I got the error:

> kotlin: Unresolved reference: SpringBootApplication

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The only dependencies that your pom defines are kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 and kotlin-test. Use https://start.spring.io to generate a correct pom.xml.

Comment: `import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication`

Answer (score 1):

This is the most "lightweight" pom.xml that I found so far that can make spring boot work with kotlin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <groupId> com.matan</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>spring-5-mvc</artifactId>
    <name>spring-5-mvc</name>
    <description>spring 5 MVC sample project about new features</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <jayway-rest-assured.version>2.9.0</jayway-rest-assured.version>
        <jackson.version>2.9.9</jackson.version> <!-- Same as spring-boot-dependencies:2.1.7.RELEASE -->
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.3.50</kotlin.version> <!-- Same as spring-boot-dependencies:2.1.7.RELEASE -->
        <start-class>com.matan.Main</start-class>
        <httpclient.version>4.5.8</httpclient.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/18593 and https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/1841 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                        <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                        <plugin>all-open</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                    <pluginOptions>
                        <option>all-open:annotation=javax.persistence.Entity</option>
                        <option>all-open:annotation=javax.persistence.Embeddable</option>
                        <option>all-open:annotation=javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass</option>
                    </pluginOptions>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>kapt</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>kapt</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                                <annotationProcessorPath>
                                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                                    <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
                                </annotationProcessorPath>
                            </annotationProcessorPaths>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```